# Can I save the email open time to my data extension using APM script on Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am sending an email to my subscriber. So when a subscriber open the email from the inbox I would like to save the email open time to the data extension using AMP script.

I am using this code:

```
%%[
VAR @SubscriberKey, @FirstOpenTimestamp

SET @SubscriberKey = _SubscriberKey
SET @FirstOpenTimestamp = NOW()

UPSERTDE('Limited Time Offer', 1, 'SubscriberKey', @SubscriberKey, 'FirstOpenTimestamp', @FirstOpenTimestamp)
]%%
```

But this code insert/ update the current time when I send the email not update when I open the email.

Any thoughts how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to use Ampscript, as it is executed at send time, and this is why you are seeing the send time, and not open time, in your data extension.

There is an existing feature tracking the opens of your emails and storing them. Marketing Cloud includes a tracking pixel, which is triggered during open. You can access data collected by the open tracking pixel in [Open data view](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_open.htm&language=en_US&type=5), which you can easily query in Automation Studio.